# What exactly is revenue leakage?

Tags: finance

I just found out about the term revenue leakage in the paper linked below. However, this paper and other resources mentioning it do not provide a definition of the term.

However, for my thesis I require such a definition.

Hence my question: Is revenue leakage a well-known term in finance? What's its formal definition or where is it properly defined?
If it is not a well-known term: Are there alternative terms that describe the same? Such as unbilled revenue, accounts receivables collection, ...

As far as I understand the notion of revenue leakage, it refers to the fact that the expected amount of revenue is not equal to (i.e. higher than) the revenue recognized or received.

Thank you

Paper referred to above: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4032101

Comment: According to [this](https://www.replicon.com/blog/reduce-revenue-leakage-and-drive-efficiency-in-professional-services/) "revenue leakage simply refers to the loss of revenue for any organization." Imho it is not a good idea for a thesis of any sort to assume that every reader knows the precise definitions of the crucial terms being used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have also seen the explanation. However, in literature I cannot find anything useful. Do you have an idea what more well-known financial concepts fit under the term 'revenue leakage'?